# issue with array in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Out of bounds

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to push to final view where the whole information about item will be shown.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)atableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
Item *itemObj; //object that holds data for cell for current view
ItemShow *itemOverViewObj; //data object for the next view 

if(atableView==self.tableView)
{
    //ordinary tabeView
    itemObj=[self.itemsArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
}
else
{
    //filtered with search tableView
    itemObj=[self.filteredItems objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
}

//The array which will store the data for overview 
NSMutableArray *itemsOverViewArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:1];
DBAccess *access=[[DBAccess alloc]init];

//method for fetching data from db and inserting into array
itemsOverViewArr=[access getItemsOverView:itemObj.itemID];
[access closeDataBase];
[access release];

//here is the evil.
itemOverViewObj=[itemsOverViewArr objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
[itemsOverViewArr release];
    ItemOverView *iov=[[ItemOverView alloc]initWithNibName:@"ItemOverView" bundle:nil];
    iov.title=self.nominal;
    [iov setItemShow:itemOverViewObj];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:iov animated:YES];
    [iov release];
}
```

What I've checked before:

Select in the method getItemsOverView works for 100%.
itemObj.itemID fetches the right int.

The problem originating in 
itemOverViewObj=[itemsOverViewArr objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

The error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

getItemsOverview meth in DBAccess Class

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getItemsOverView:(int)itemID
{
NSMutableArray *itemsArray=[[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];
const char *sqlItems=sqlite3_mprintf("SELECT itm.itemID,itm.itemYear,itm.rarity,dateComment,itm.mintage,dc.dateCode as dateCode,iaval.availability as avalibility,iaval.quality as quality,itm.Mintmark,itm.specialRemark\
                                     from items itm\
                                     join itemAvailability iaval on iaval.itemID=itm.itemID\
                                     join dateCultures dc ON dc.dateCultureID=itm.dateCulture\
                                     WHERE itm.itemID=%i",itemID);
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlItems, -1, &statement, NULL);
if ( sqlResult== SQLITE_OK)
{
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        ItemShow *itemShow=[[ItemShow alloc]init];
        itemShow.itemID=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        char *itemYear=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
        char *mintMark=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2);
        char *masterMark=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
        itemShow.rarity=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 4);
        itemShow.availability=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 5);
        itemShow.quality=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 6);
        char *mintage=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 7);

        itemShow.itemYear=(itemYear)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:itemYear]:@"";
        itemShow.mintMark=(mintMark)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:mintMark]:@"";
        itemShow.masterMark=(masterMark)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:masterMark]:@"";
        itemShow.mintage=(mintage)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:mintage]:@"Unknown";



        [itemsArray addObject:itemShow];
        [itemShow release];

    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
else
{
    [self dbConnectionError];
}

return itemsArray;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception message says it all: You are trying to access the second item (index 1) in `itemsOverViewArr` but this array only contains one item (index 0).

Why that is so only you can tell since you don't show us the relevant code. But it sure looks like `[access getItemsOverView:itemObj.itemID]` returns an array containing 1 element.

Also, you have at least one memory leak in your code. The array created by `NSMutableArray *itemsOverViewArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:1];` is no longer reachable after the line `itemsOverViewArr=[access getItemsOverView:itemObj.itemID];` and thus cannot be released. The fact that you are releasing `itemsOverViewArr` later is probably also a memory management error (in this case an overrelease) because `getItemsOverView:` should return an autoreleased object. (Btw, you should not name such methods `get...` as this naming convention implies in Cocoa that the method returns its results via a pointer to one of the method's arguments.)

Comment: it not empty after itemsOverViewArr=[access getItemsOverView:itemObj.itemID];, I wrote  NSLog(@"%d",[itemsOverViewArr count]); to check if it really getting filled up. I am getting 1. So it's getting filled up.

Comment: @Nathan 1 means one element and that needs to be addressed using objectAtIndex:0 as indexing an array is zero based. Your original quote however suggested that the array was empty indeed - so either your quote is incorrect or your latest NSLog result.

Comment: And what about this implementation?: NSMutableArray * itemsOverViewArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [access getItemsOverView:itemObj.itemID]];

Comment: Ok. meanwhile this question is closed, cos the reason of issue is identified. Another question will be opened.

Answer (score 0):

What does:

```
itemsOverViewArr=[access getItemsOverView:itemObj.itemID];
```

do?

If it returns an array, declare your NSMutableArray like this:

```
NSMutableArray * itemsOverViewArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [access getItemsOverView:itemObj.itemID]];
```

And then also make sure, when referencing it, to make certain that there's at least one item in that mutable array.

In other words:

```
if(itemsOverViewArr && ([itemsOverViewArr count] > 1)) 
{
    itemOverViewObj=[itemsOverViewArr objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: It was already declared in my code before: NSMutableArray *itemsOverViewArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:1];

Comment: true... you could replace that declaration you put above with what I just gave you in the answer, or you could also do [`[itemsOverViewArr setArray:[access getItemsOverView:itemObj.itemID]];`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/setArray:) (documentation linked for you).

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[Items count]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x15f6c'

Comment: And itemsOverViewArr is not empty. it's full of data.

Comment: gah... typo on my part, I've fixed the code above (from `itemOverViewObj` to `itemsOverViewArr`).

Comment: Well, now it's empty. My code is: NSMutableArray * itemsOverViewArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: [access getItemsOverView:itemObj.itemID]]; itemOverViewObj=[itemsOverViewArr objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

Comment: I knew about you made the typo and repaired it by myself before. Even with this typo I understood your logic.

Comment: It sounds like you're narrowing in on your solution through your hard work & debugging skills.  No more crashing! :-)

Comment: Damn, it's some magic. array is not empty and if(itemsOverViewArr && [itemsOverViewArr count]>1) ... {else} NSLog(@"Error"); Throughs me to error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your using the delegate for more than one tableView

```
if(atableView==self.tableView)
```

Make sure you accessing the right tableview here:

```
itemOverViewObj=[itemsOverViewArr objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
```

or you will get the wrong index into the array, which may only have one item at index 0, which would make index 1 beyond bounds.

Comment: if(atableView==self.tableView)
    {
        //ordinary tabeView
        itemObj=[self.itemsArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    }
    else
    {
        //filtered with search tableView
        itemObj=[self.filteredItems objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    }

Comment: first one is normal table. another one this table after sorting with UISearch. Both of them may be used.

Comment: Do an NSLog to see whats in the itemsOverViewArr right before the crash to see whats in it. And what the indexPath is, thats being called. I use [indexPath description].

Comment: I really know nothing about sqlite but just as a suggestion you could check whats inside itemsArray right before it returns it. I would add some NSLogs to see where  and if it has any objects and where it doesn't. I'm sorry I can't help you more.

Comment: -(NSMutableArray*)getItemsOverView:(int)itemID online. this method fetches the data from db.