# NSMutableArray won't fill up

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am trying to fill up an NSmutableAray with data from sqlite database.

ItemShow class:

```
@interface ItemShow : NSObject 
{
NSInteger itemID;
NSString *itemYear;
NSInteger rarity;
NSString *mintage;
NSInteger availability;
NSInteger quality;
NSString *mintMark;
NSString *masterMark;
NSString *dateCode;
NSString *dateDescription;
}
```

Getters/setters are ok

Method in DBAccess class:

```
-(NSMutableArray*)getItemsOverView:(int)itemID
{
NSMutableArray *itemsArray=[[[NSMutableArray alloc]init]autorelease];
const char *sqlItems=sqlite3_mprintf("SELECT itm.itemID,itm.itemYear,itm.rarity,itm.mintage,iaval.availability as avalibility,iaval.quality as quality,itm.Mintmark,itm.masterMark,dc.dateCode,dc.dateDescription\
                                     from items as itm\
                                     join itemAvailability as iaval on iaval.itemID=itm.itemID\
                                     join dateCultures as dc ON dc.dateCultureID=itm.dateCulture\
                                     WHERE itm.itemID=%i",itemID);
sqlite3_stmt *statement;
int sqlResult = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlItems, -1, &statement, NULL);
if ( sqlResult== SQLITE_OK)
{
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        ItemShow *itemShow=[[ItemShow alloc]init];
        itemShow.itemID=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
        char *itemYear=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
        itemShow.rarity=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 2);
        char *mintage=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3);
        itemShow.availability=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 4);
        itemShow.quality=sqlite3_column_int(statement, 5);
        char *mintMark=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 6);
        char *masterMark=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 7);
        char *dateCode=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 8);
        char *dateDescription=(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 9);

        itemShow.itemYear=(itemYear)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:itemYear]:@"";
        itemShow.mintMark=(mintMark)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:mintMark]:@"";
        itemShow.masterMark=(masterMark)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:masterMark]:@"";
        itemShow.mintage=(mintage)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:mintage]:@"Unknown";
        itemShow.dateCode=(dateCode)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:dateCode]:@"";
        itemShow.dateCode=(dateDescription)?[NSString stringWithUTF8String:dateDescription]:@"";

        [itemsArray addObject:itemShow];
        [itemShow release];

    }
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
}
else
{
    [self dbConnectionError];
}

return itemsArray;
}
```

code in ViewDidLoad

```
DBAccess *dbAccess=[[DBAccess alloc]init];
self.dataArr=[dbAccess getItemsOverView:itemID];
   // ItemShow *itmShow=[dataArr objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"%d",[dataArr count]); //returns 1. So, empty array
[dbAccess closeDataBase];
[dbAccess release];
```

Same construction works fine in other views, but now it gives error - empty array out of bounds.

What was checked

1. Select works. checked it in SQLiteStudio
2. itemID is int and the view getting it correct from previous view like it gets title.

Comment: If [dataArr count] is 1, then the array is not empty. Were you expecting more than one result?

Comment: Read my other todays posting. It has to be more then 1

Comment: @Nathan, why does it have to be more than one? It looks like your SQL statement is designed to return one row (`WHERE itm.itemID=%i`), and you get one item out. I fail to see the problem...

Comment: @joerick http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778178/issue-with-array-in-didselectrowatindexpath-out-of-bounds

Comment: Looks like you could be returning an ItemShow Object rather than an NSMutableArray from the method.

Comment: Nathan, how many times do you iterate through ` while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)` ?  (An NSLog will tell you.)  The array won't fill itself.

Comment: @Hot Licks So much as method from DBccess class will return. What do you mean?

Comment: @Hubert Kunnemeyer return itemsArray;

Comment: @Hot Licks It brought me 0 entries. P.S I am not an idiot. I am a moron. There's difference.

Comment: Then your problem must be with the database query, right??

Comment: No. Select works. checked it in SQLiteStudio. This method is exact copy of another working method. the only difference is more items in select and of cause additional conditions in sqlResult== SQLITE_OK block.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Have resolved it by myself. Just made new method. Now it works